# rspec-sinatra, how to call a helper method?

Tags: rspec, sinatra

I have a Sinatra application.

it includes the following:

```
helpers do
  def helper1
    ...code...
  end
  def helper2
    ...code...
  end
  ...
end
```

How can I test these helper methods?

Currently my rspec has:

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

require_relative '../app'  # <-- your sinatra app

describe 'Basic test' do

  before :each do
    @xml_info = File.read('examples/request_litle_auth.xml')
  end 
  it "basic test" do
    'a'.should eq 'a' 
  end 
  it "can call a helper method" do
    to_dollars(30)
  end 
end
```

but that gives:

```
undefined method `to_dollars' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x00000002460e18>
```

Answer (score 1):

classical sinatra testing works with `Rack::Test`. this is a fake browser session that performs requests against your sinatra application, so that you can assert response codes, content etc.

if you want to test a custom defined helper method, you will need to something similar to this: https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/issues/930

TL;DR

create a module, include it in your helper call, test the module in any fashion you like.